# Get the matching records from web based on the input keywords for data analytic's

Tags: web, extract, sentiment-analysis, c3.js

I want to get the data from web matching my keyword (from as many sources as possible).

I want to do this for sentiment analysis. For e.g. if I want to know about iphone6 then it should get data about iphone6 from all possible sources including apple sites and all other popular review sites etc...

Can you please help me with this about how to go ahead with this thing. I am looking for a solution for this in c3.

Answer (score 0):

http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-display/

Using this library you can perform keyword based search from twitter.

You can collect text for each received tweets and perform sentiment analysis for the same.